# Why does Hudson ignore my profiles.xml file?

Tags: java, maven-2, continuous-integration, hudson

I have a Maven2 project, with a pom.xml and a profiles.xml files at the same level.
The project configuration is provided by Maven profile properties:

```
dbhost=${dbhost}
dbport=${dbport}
// etc.
```

Locally, each developper customize his build in the "profiles.xml". It works well.

For continuous integration, a ci "profiles.xml" has been put on our SCM server (at the same level as the pom.xml).

The problem is that Hudson simply ignores this file during the Maven build, whereas the "-P hudsonprofile" is correctly set.

If the same profile is moved directly in the "pom.xml", or in the global "settings.xml" the build works. So we already have a solution.

I also know that the "profiles.xml" file is deprecated, but I would like to understand why the comportement is different between Hudson build and my local build...

Note: Hudson and my local build use the same version of Maven (2.2.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a classpath problem to me. Why would Hudson not notice the profiles.xml? The only reason I can think of is that Hudson uses a different classpath than you would expect.

A best practice (atleast in my experience), is to try to build the project from the command line on your CI server (where Hudson runs). If that works, then Hudson should work too. Unless you have configured Maven in Hudson weirdly.

Also, adjusting the settings.xml of Maven is not that bad. At least, if you dont expect it to change too much. Even so, it is fixed quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is defining the profiles directly in your pom.xml file for both CI specifically and then generically for local builds. Then the devs can override any profile settings in their own personal settings.xml file for local builds. This has the added benefit of not having to check-in a profiles.xml file which will not work for devs, forcing them to modify this versioned file and remember to not check in their changes. This also has the added benefit on making your build not dependent on a deprecated feature of Maven. After all, I would not count on the behavior of a deprecated feature in the first place. Hopefully this is an elegant solution which uses ideas from what you know already works.